# Displaying info in wedges of Pie chart in Core-plot?

Tags: core-plot, cppiechart

How can we display info in a label, inside each of the wedges in a pie chart developed using Core-plot? I was able to label outside the wedge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use data labels. Several of the example programs demonstrate how. All Core Plot plot types can be labeled using the same mechanism.